# How to make a matrices of matrices (or block matrix)

Tags: matrix

I'm trying to construct a matrix H[i,j] that satisfies the "If" condition, in this case, if i==f then the main diagonal has a matrix stored, and also, the other non diagonal terms that are matrices too. How to return the full H[i,j] matrix from this loop?

```
   n = 2;
 \[Epsilon] = \[CapitalAlpha];



 For[j = 0, j < n + 1, j++,
  For[i = 0, i < n + 1, i++,
    If[i == j,

      Subscript[H, i, j] = 
       Table[If[i == j - 1, t, 0], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}] + 
        Table[If[i == j + 1, t, 0], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}] +
        Table[If[i == j, \[Epsilon], 0], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]
      ,

      Subscript[H, i, j] = t*IdentityMatrix[n]             ];
    ];

  ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = 2;
ArrayFlatten[
 Table[
  If[i == j,
   Table[t Boole[Abs[i - j] == 1] + ϵ Boole[i == j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}],
   t IdentityMatrix[n]
   ],
  {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Array[Subscript[H, ##] &, {n, n}]
```

BTW, I am almost certain that there are more convenient ways to define your `H`.